# Flink-CEP use of hashCode and equals

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Does Flink-CEP use `hashCode()` and `equals()` for comparison if the pattern definition only has attribute level comparisons?

I'm asking because I can't guarantee `hashCode()` correctness.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Flink uses Equals() and hashcode() to while comparing events. I always create these methods in IntelliJ by pressing *command + N* and then selection *equals and hashcode methods*.